# Download telerik.cms.engine.dll

Tags: telerik

I have tried this article http://www.sitefinitywatch.com/blog/09-06-16/Email_Notification_about_New_Blog_Comments.aspx in sitefnity project. but in project , in bin folder there is not found telerik.cms.engine.dll .

I have tried to downoad telerik.cms dlls from telerik site but not found. Please can you suugest us from where we can download telerik dlls.

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy Telerik products, they are not available for free download.